# How many keys can one have with an account? Active, Owner, and Claim?

Tags: accounts, claim

I just saw one of the eos accounts has a "claim" key. What is the claim key for and how is it different from the rest?

Comment: you can make as many custom permission as you want beyond active and owner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically you can create as many key as you want and as many permission as you want.

A single key pair can be related to multiple permission. Moreover you can specify a permission name and link a permission to a specified action in a smart contract.

The 'claim' key you said is a key (permission) created by the owner of the account, it's just a name. Active and owner, on the other hand, are mandatory and have fixed name.

You can find an awesome video (IMO) that talks about permission, [on youtube, in the EOS Canada channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rIJhY3ZGQtk).